# Переменная повторно выводит старые значения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку на страницу при помощи innerHTML выводилось то,что пользователь написал в value нескольких inputов(добавляется новая заметка с датой). Написал функцию, при первом добавлении все добавляется на страницу и отображается нормально, но при втором(если хочу добавить и вставить еще одну заметку) - на страницу еще раз выводится и старая заметка, и новая, то есть повторяется старая, а мне нужно чтобы выводилась только новая. Подозреваю что это связанно с переменной displayInv, подскажите как быть?

```
let button = document.getElementById('save_btn')



let invoices = [ ]


button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  let invoice_obj = {
    no: number.value,
    create: inv_date.value,
    supply: sup_date.value,
    comments: comment.value
  }
  invoices.push(invoice_obj)
  displayInvoices ()
  


})

function displayInvoices () {
  invoices.forEach(function (item, index) {
    
     let displayInv = `
    <li>
    ${item.create}
    </li>
    <li>
    ${item.no}
    </li>
    <li>
    ${item.supply}
    </li>
    <li>
    ${item.comments}
    </li>
    
    `
  
     var li = document.createElement('ul')
      li.id='ok'
      li.innerHTML = displayInv
    
    document.getElementById('qwe').appendChild(li)
   
  })
  
  number.value = "";
  inv_date.value = "";
  sup_date.value = "";
  comment.value = "";
 

  
}
```

Comment: Можете предоставить HTML разметку, чтобы можно было запустить код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В чем ваша проблема:
Вы каждый раз перебираете массив объектов и добавляете их на страницу.

Вариант 1:
Очищать блок перед добавляем элементов.
То есть перед строкой:

```js
invoices.forEach(function (item, index) {
```

Нужно добавить данный код:

```js
document.getElementById('qwe').innerHTML = '';
```

Или же этот (он производительней прошлого):

```js
let div = document.getElementById('qwe');
while(div.firstChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}
```

Должно получиться что-то такое:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('save_btn');
const blockInvoices = document.getElementById('qwe');

let invoices = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function () {

    let invoice_obj = {
        no      : number.value,
        create  : inv_date.value,
        supply  : sup_date.value,
        comments: comment.value
    };

    number.value   = "";
    inv_date.value = "";
    sup_date.value = "";
    comment.value  = "";

    invoices.push(invoice_obj);
    displayInvoices();
});

function displayInvoices() {

    while(blockInvoices.firstChild) {
        blockInvoices.removeChild(blockInvoices.firstChild);
    }
    // or
    // blockInvoices.innerHTML = '';

    invoices.forEach(function (item, index) {

        let displayInv = `
        <li>
            ${item.create}
        </li>
        <li>
            ${item.no}
        </li>
        <li>
            ${item.supply}
        </li>
        <li>
            ${item.comments}
        </li>
        `;
    
        let li           = document.createElement('ul');
            li.id        = 'ok';
            li.innerHTML = displayInv;
        
        blockInvoices.appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

---

Вариант 2 (я бы выбрал его):
Вы можете передавать объект `invoice_obj` в функцию и из него напрямую получать данные, дабы не перебирать каждый раз массив `invoices`.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('save_btn');
const blockInvoices = document.getElementById('qwe');

// let invoices = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function () {

    let invoice_obj = {
        no      : number.value,
        create  : inv_date.value,
        supply  : sup_date.value,
        comments: comment.value
    };
    
    number.value   = "";
    inv_date.value = "";
    sup_date.value = "";
    comment.value  = "";

    // invoices.push(invoice_obj)
    displayInvoices(invoice_obj);
});

function displayInvoices(item) {

    let displayInv = `
    <li>
        ${item.create}
    </li>
    <li>
        ${item.no}
    </li>
    <li>
        ${item.supply}
    </li>
    <li>
        ${item.comments}
    </li>
    `;

    let li           = document.createElement('ul');
        li.id        = 'ok';
        li.innerHTML = displayInv;
    
    blockInvoices.appendChild(li);
}
```

---

Вариант 3:
Вы можете указывать свойство `show: 0` для объекта и потом в функции получать только их, затем устанавливая им значение `1`, но смысл, если всегда будет создавать только один новый объект (судя из вашего кода).

---

Хочу вот еще что добавить, вы каждый раз создаете новый `ul` с `id="ok"`, это не правильно, на странице должен находится только один элемент с таким именем индификатора.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, помогло. Где я могу отметить ваш ответ как решение?

Comment: Ну я думаю вы справились с этой задачей)